# Como usar PDO no slimfamework 4?

Tags: php, slim, slimframework

Alguém poderia me dizer como eu instancio o PDO em um arquivo no slim framework usando o `app->get`?

fiz na configuração no arquivo settings e no dependencies porem não sei como chamar a conexão em outro arquivo para fazer um select por exemplo.

```
use DI\ContainerBuilder;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;

return function (ContainerBuilder $containerBuilder) {
    $containerBuilder->addDefinitions([
        PDO::class => function (ContainerInterface $c) {
            $dbSettings = $c->get('settings')['db1'];
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $dbSettings['host'] . ';dbname=' . $dbSettings['dbname'];
            $options = [
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            ];
            return new PDO($dsn, $dbSettings['user'], $dbSettings['pass'], $options);
        },
    ]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Opa,

Como você configurou o DependencyInjection, basta chamar no construtor da sua Action

```
public function __construct(\PDO $pdo)
{
    // sua lógica aqui
}
```

Faltou também na sua configuração a barra antes do PDO => \PDO, fica assim:

```
\PDO::class => function (ContainerInterface $c)
```